# Python-"is"-like equality operator for Haskell/GHC

Tags: haskell, reference, ghc

Is there a GHC-specific "unsafe" extension to ask whether two Haskell references point to the same location?

I'm aware this can break referential transparency if not used properly. But there should be little harm (unless I'm missing something), if it is used very careful, as a means for optimizations by short-cutting recursive (or expensive) data traversal, e.g. for implementing an optimized `Eq` instance, e.g.:

```
instance Eq ComplexTree where
   a == b  = (a `unsafeSameRef` b) || (a `deepCompare` b)
```

providing `deepCompare` is guaranteed to be true if `unsafeSameRef` decides true (but not necessarily the other way around).

**EDIT/PS**: Thanks to the answer pointing to `System.Mem.StableName`, I was able to also find the paper [Stretching the storage manager: weak pointers and stable names in Haskell](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.7399) which happens to have addressed this very problem already over 10 years ago...

Comment: I've often wanted exactly this feature, for exactly this purpose: a faster equality check.

Comment: @FUZxxl: if he asks that (and the question indicates quite clearly that he knows what he's talking about), then obviously he needs that. Blaming OP in performing premature optimization without knowing his problem is a bit... premature.

Comment: @Roman Cheplyaka: Sorry. I don't wanted the comment to be rude, so I've deleted it.

Comment: +1 For perfectly asked question. However, I would trust the compiler to automatically do this optimization for me. Does it not?

Comment: @Tarrasch: no, there are lots of reasons not to do that. Particularly, equality is not quite reflexive, as Lennart Augustsson pointed out in his response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GHC's [System.Mem.StableName](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/System-Mem-StableName.html) solves exactly this problem.

Answer (score 9):

There's a pitfall to be aware of:

Pointer equality can change strictness.  I.e., you might get pointer equality saying True when in fact the real equality test would have looped because of, e.g., a circular structure.  So pointer equality ruins the semantics (but you knew that).

Answer (score 2):

I think StablePointers might be of help here
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Foreign-StablePtr.html
Perhaps this is the kind of solution you are looking for:

```
import Foreign.StablePtr (newStablePtr, freeStablePtr)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

unsafeSameRef :: a -> a -> Bool
unsafeSameRef x y = unsafePerformIO $ do
    a <- newStablePtr x
    b <- newStablePtr y
    let z = a == b
    freeStablePtr a
    freeStablePtr b
    return z;
```

Comment: `StableName` would behave the way you suggest. `StablePtr` does not do any deduplication/sharing. It does not go through a hash table or such at all.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update. I see the shortcomings of `StablePtr` for this use.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`unpackClosure#` in GHC.Prim](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#v%3aunpackClosure-35-), with the following type:

```
unpackClosure# :: a -> (# Addr#,Array# b,ByteArray# #)
```

Using that you could whip up something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, UnboxedTuples #-} 
import GHC.Prim

eq a b = case unpackClosure# a of 
    (# a1,a2,a3 #) -> case unpackClosure# b of 
        (# b1,b2,b3 #) -> eqAddr# a1 b1
```

And in the same package, there's the interestingly named [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#v%3areallyUnsafePtrEquality-35-) of type

```
reallyUnsafePtrEquality#  :: a -> a -> Int#
```

But I'm not sure what the return value of that one is - going by the name it will lead to much gnashing of teeth.

Comment: @yatima2975: I asked a question about what `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` does in the #ghc channel. The answer was: *FUZxxl: (...) but it takes two objects and tells you whether their addresses in memory are the same (=> they are the same object)*. You can even try in ghci! But then, you see, where the problem is: It only works in some cases.

Comment: It returns 0# for inequality and 1# for equality. But notice, that there may be both false negatives and false positives.

Comment: @FYZxxl false negatives *and* false positives...in other words...it's useless?

Comment: @FUZxxl - Thanks for finding that out! False negatives aren't so bad (for the question-asker) as he'll just have to do a 'normal' comparison, but the possibility of false positives makes `reallyUnsafePtrEquality` completely useless for this problem. Presumably, the positives arise due to objects being moved by the GC?

Comment: @Dan They should rename it `reallyUselessPtrEquality#` then :)

Comment: @yatima2975: AFAIK, false positives are possible when using different types. In IRC, somebody said, that `let x = [] :: [Char]; y = [] : [Int] in reallyUnsafePtrEquality# x y` may yield `1#` under some compiler optimizations. Moving objects shouldn't be an issue, since all pointers are updated while GC.

Comment: Thus, `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#` should be safe for day-to-day uses, but only when it is backed up by a deep equality test.