# How do I compare recursive data structures?

Tags: haskell

I have a complex and recursive data structure which I have simplified to the following:

```
data Node = Node { value :: Integer, next :: Node } deriving (Show,Eq)
```

Given the following expressions:

```
--Create a circular structure
a = Node 1 b
b = Node 0 a --Tie the knot
c = Node 1 b --Another structure which points to b
```

The expressions `a` and `c` are conceptually equal: they both represent a node which holds the value 1 and points to the expression b. My question is: how do I check that they are indeed equal in a Haskell expression? If I evaluate `a == c` it will keep evaluating sub-elements in the circular structure forever.

Is it possible to perform such a comparison in Haskell?

EDIT: In my case, I am trying to compare the two for inspection/debugging purposes. But another reason to do this could be for unit testing.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python-"is"-like equality operator for Haskell/GHC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701893/python-is-like-equality-operator-for-haskell-ghc)

Comment: Seeing as I'm doing this project as an exercise to learn Haskell and test all of its possibilities, I would like to avoid GHC-specific extensions if at all possible.

Comment: It's not possible without GHC extensions (and it's iffy even with them) unless you give each Node an explicit ID-value and compare them using IDs.

Comment: It's not possible in general.  The problem is that semantic equality is not decidable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, *a* and *b* are not equal, but *a* and *c* are equal, not just conceptually, but they are in fact the same thing.

To answer your question:  there is no drop-in solution to your problem.  If you need identity comparison, you first have to establish a notion of identity.  One way to do this is to have a `Map` from keys to nodes:

```
data Node k =
    Node {
      nodeValue :: Integer,
      nodeNext  :: k
    }
```

The idea is that you have a separate `Map` from keys of type *k* to nodes.  However, you can't write an `Eq` instance for that one.  A somewhat elegant way to solve this is to use [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Reflection

data Node n k =
    Node {
      nodeValue :: Integer,
      nodeNext  :: k
    }

instance (n `Reifies` Map k (Node n k)) => Eq (Node n k) where
    (==) = {- ... -}
        where
        nodeMap :: Map k (Node n k)
        nodeMap = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

Another option that gained some attention recently is the notion of [observable sharing](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2013/2013-01-14-observable-sharing.md).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I did mean to say that `a` and `c` were equal, not `a` and `b`. I have corrected my question. Thank you for the clear answer, I will test if any of these solutions work in my case and get back to you as soon as possible!

Comment: The observable sharing notion is very interesting but seems to steer away from the philosophy of Haskell. The reason why I marked this as the answer is the very first sentence: "`a` and `c` are equal, not just conceptually, but they are in fact the same thing". That means that if I want to distinguish between two Nodes which hold the same value and point to the same "next" Node, then I need to revise my definition of Node to include some sort of unique ID field. Thank you SO much!

Answer (score -2):

If you promise to use it only for testing and debugging, and not for application code, you can also use my [ghc-heap-view](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view) library, which gives you a low-level view onto the Haskell heap and would enable you to implement a comparison:

```
Prelude> :script /home/jojo/.cabal/share/ghc-heap-view-0.4.0.0/ghci 
Prelude> data Node = Node { value :: Integer, next :: Node } deriving (Show,Eq)
Prelude> let { a = Node 1 b; b = Node 0 a ; c = Node 1 b}
Prelude> take 100 (show a) -- make sure it is evaluated, we are not interested in thunks here
"Node {value = 1, next = Node {value = 0, next = Node {value = 1, next = Node {value = 0, next = Node"
Prelude> take 100 (show c) -- dito
"Node {value = 1, next = Node {value = 0, next = Node {value = 1, next = Node {value = 0, next = Node"
Prelude> System.Mem.performGC
Prelude> :printHeap a
let x0 = Node (S# 1) (Node (S# 0) x0)
in x0
Prelude> :printHeap c
let x2 = Node (S# 0) (Node (S# 1) x2)
in Node (S# 1) x2
```

But this is certainly not the right thing to do for you now, given you are „doing this project as an exercise to learn Haskell”.